# Find smallest number m such that $9^{32} + 19^{433} + m$ is divisible by $4$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

We went over this in class awhile ago, but I can't seem to figure out how to solve it. Obviously you can do it exhaustively with a supercomputer, but that doesn't seem practical when I know there's a simplistic way to solve it.

Comment: Have you tried looking at the number mod 4?

Comment: It’s a good idea to make your question self-contained, rather than having essential parts only in the title.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$9\equiv 1\pmod4$, so every power of $9$ is also congruent to $1\bmod 4$; in particular, $9^{32}\equiv 1\pmod 4$. $19\equiv -1\pmod 4$, so $19^{433}\equiv(-1)^{433}\equiv -1\pmod 4$, since $(-1)^{433}=-1$. Thus, $$9^{32}+19^{433}\equiv 1+(-1)\equiv 0\pmod 4\;,$$ meaning that $9^{32}+19^{433}$ is divisible by $4$. The smallest non-negative $m$ such that $9^{32}+19^{433}+m$ is divisible by $4$ is therefore $0$, and the smallest positive $m$ is $4$.

Comment: How does 9 = 1 mod 4?

Comment: How many times can you divide 9 by 4 and what is the remainder after doing that?

Comment: @Doug: To verify that $9\equiv 1\pmod 4$, recall that by definition $a\equiv b\pmod m$ if and only if $m\mid a-b$. Certainly $4\mid 8=9-1$, so $9\equiv 1\pmod 4$. To calculate it from scratch, just divide $9$ by $4$: you get a quotient of $2$ and a remainder of $1$, meaning that $9=2\cdot 4+1$. Thus, $9$ and $1$ differ by a multiple of $4$, so they must be congruent mod $4$. More generally, if $a$ and $b$ have the same remainder when divided by $m$, they must be congruent mod $m$.

Comment: @DougSmith $9 \neq 1 ~ \mathrm{mod} ~ 4$, however $9 \equiv 1 ~ \mathrm{mod} ~ 4$ (congruence) - it's important to distinguish them.

Answer (score 4):

Since you've gotten the mathematical answer already, I'd like to point out that it's not a particularly hard problem computationally (and certainly doesn't require a supercomputer).  It can be computed in [GAP](http://www.gap-system.org/) as follows:

```
gap> 9^32+19^433;
501544200119392562625247277746089908092336003464306403005859888420683628454522\
294504197711028243108230887275382154581016491417414644491962851915431414455652\
288045095893781599660030753306640524923972275437754069448537906581323068453513\
432352483965776742110824103821944465300751947471969610305958014477196847328310\
211743932024655151477385264075258820700008154477693517186089623494722993687602\
585620203537058139081722096639662034404319726334084194425480243598759870559077\
000920199390664370931533991434513332012987998517097840035144875728681773054413\
22534740
gap> last mod 4;
0
```

Since every 4-th integer is divisible by 4, and $9^{32}+19^{433}$ is divisible by 4, we can deduce that $9^{32}+19^{433}+m$ is divisible by $4$ if and only if $m$ is divisible by $4$.

This was computed on my home computer, and took less than a microsecond to compute (it took me significantly longer to type `9^32+19^433;`).  You could similarly compute it using a zillion other computer algebra systems, or even Wolfram|Alpha.

(Note: while I'm not advocating solely relying on computers to solve mathematical problems, I think it's useful to know what the computer will be able to do.)

Comment: You could've also performed modular exponentiation (taking the result modulo $4$ at each iteration) which is more efficient in the general case, though for such a small case it's not important. Computational results can sometimes give insight into a problem.

Comment: @Thomas: thanks for pointing this out. Just in case, GAP could do it with `PowerModInt`, e.g. `PowerModInt(19,433,4);`

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** $\rm\,\ mod\ n\!:\ (an\!+\!1)^j + (bn\!-\!1)^{2k+1}\equiv 1^j + (-1)^{2k+1}\equiv 1-1\equiv 0$

Answer (score 1):

I presume “the smallest number *m*” here is intended in the sense of “the smallest non-negative integer *m*”.  Assuming this, I’d suggest:

- first, show that for any number *n*, “what’s the smallest number *m* such that *n* + *m* is divisible by 4” is equivalent to a slightly different question about *n*, in a more standard form.
- secondly, use techniques about powers (which you’ve hopefully seen) to answer that question.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you can do this simply by modding out:
$$
9^{32}\equiv 81^{16}\equiv 1^{16}\equiv 1 \mod 4
$$
$$
19^{433}\equiv (-1)^{433}\equiv -1 \mod 4
$$

Adding these, we see $9^{32}+19^{433}$ is divisible by four, so $m=0$ is valid. I assume you mean the smallest absolute value, as you can just make negative multiples of four.  Hope that's what you were looking for!

Comment: Do you mean $\mod 20$ or $\mod 4$?  Also (FYI), you need to fix the math formatting in the second paragraph... (the powers)

Comment: How did you get the 19 = -1?

Comment: Oops.  I have no clue how how a got 20.  Luckily, it works, and I'll fix that now.  @ Doug, $19\equiv 3\equiv -1$ since modular arithmetic can easily be applied in negative numbers, and it is clear $19-5\cdot 4=-1$.